# How can I get all keys from each NSDictionary in an NSArray without loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an array containing NSDictionary .each dictionary contains only one key value pair.I want to get all keys in array.i can get all values by key in array easily.
Please tell me how to get all keys in seprate array

my array with dictionary looks like

```
(
        {
        key = array;
    },
        {
        key1 = Array;
    },
        {
        key2 = With;
    },
        {
        key3 = dict;
    },
        {
        key4 = hello;
    }
)
```

i want array having [key1,key2,key3,key4]
Thanks.

Comment: I think it will be worse without a loop.

Comment: Perform an operation that does something to every item in an array... that's pretty much the definition of a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still worried about one situation of having similar *keys* in multiple Dictionaries inside your Array. The main thing for any Dictionary is that each of its content must have different *keys*. So, I recommend you to go with a solution that can generate an Array of Keys from the Dictionary having different *keys*.

**Input :**

```
(
    {
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
    },
        {
        y = 3;
        z = 4;
    },
        {
        x = 6;
        z = 5;
    }
)
```

**Sample Code :**

```
NSArray *uniqueKeys = [arrayWithKeys valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.@allKeys"];
```

**Output :**

```
(
    y,
    z,
    x
)
```

Comment: This will work. But remove the `@` before `allKeys`. Also, your keys will each be wrapped in a `NSArray`.

Comment: @NSAddict : Nope. My code will work perfectly. I tested and you can see the results, I added in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question says "without loop", but this iteration over enum is nice and clean.

```
//myArray is your array that is "containing NSDictionary(s)"

// Create an array to store the keys
NSMutableArray *arrayWithKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myArray count];

// Iterate through the array 
for (NSDictionary *dict in myArray) {
 [arrayWithKeys addObject:[dict allkeys]]; // add the key 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray *yourArray = @[@{@"a":@"1"},@{@"aa":@"1"},@{@"aaa":@"1"},@{@"aaaa":@"1"},@{@"aaaaa":@"1"}];

    NSMutableArray *keys =  [NSMutableArray array];

    [yourArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        [keys addObjectsFromArray:[obj allKeys]];

    }];

    NSLog(@"%@",keys);
```

Comment: That is using a loop.

Comment: Somewhere down in the code, so is every possible answer to this question. By definition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own class?

This would simplify many things.

Considering you made a class called `ModelClass` with the properties `key` and `value`,
you could do this:

```
NSArray *keys = [arrayWithKeys valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (int j=0; j<[yourArray count]; j++)
{
    NSDictionary* dict =[yourArray objectAtIndex:j];
    for (NSString* key in [dict allKeys]) {
            [array addObject:key];
    }
}
NSLog(@"array===%@",array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray *arrayofKeys = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSDictionary * dict in array){

   [arrayofKeys addObjectsFromArray:[dict allKeys]];
}

NSLog(@"The collection keys :: %@",arrayofKeys);
```